# Javascript object oriented pirate translator

Tags: javascript

I need to make an object oriented pirate translator in javascript for my final, I have an idea and have some code but can't get it to output correctly on my page.  I have it set up so you type the english phrase in one box and then in the other box it spits out the pirate version.  I will not step through my array of objects.  I will post code.  Thanks for any help I can get!!!

```
 var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }


var Dictionary = [{
    Greetings: {
        hello:"ahoy",
        hi:"yohoho",
        pardon_me:"avast",
        excuse_me:"arrr"
    },
    People: {
        stranger:"scurvy",
        sir:"matey",
        madam:"proud beauty",
        miss:"comely wench",
        officer:"foul blaggart",
        enemy:"scallywag"
    },
    Questions: {
        where_is:"whar be",
        can_you_help_me_find:"know ye",
        is_that:"be that",
        how_far_is_it_to:"how many leagues to"
    },
    Articles: {
        the:"th",
        a:"a briny",
        any:"some godforsaken",
        nearby:"broadside",
        my:"me",
        your:"yer"
    },
    Adjectives: {
        old:"barnacle-covered",
        attractive:"comely",
        happy:"grog-filled"
    },
    Places: {
        restroom:"head",
        restaurant:"galley",
        hotel:"fleabag inn",
        mall:"market",
        pub:"Skull & Scuppers",
        bank:"buried trasure"
    },
    Desires: {
        I_would_like_to:"I be needin to",
        I_desire:"I have a fierce fire in me belly",
        I_wish_I_knew_how_to:"I be hankerin to",
        my_mother_told_me_to:"me dear ol mum, bless her black soul, tol me to",
        my_companion_would_like_to:"me mate, ol Rumpot, wants to"
    },
    Actions: {
        find:"come across",
        take_a_nap:"have a bit of a lie down",
        make_a_withdrawal:"seize all yer doubloons",
        have_a_cocktail:"swill a pint or two of grog",
        kill_him:"blow the man down",
        frown:"hang the jib",
        take_a_hike:"walk the plank"
    },

}];

function Translate(text)
    // Returns: a copy of text with English phrases replaced by piratey equivalents 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Dictionary.length; i++) {
            var toReplace = new RegExp("\\b"+Dictionary[i][0]+"\\b", "i");

            var index = text.search(toReplace);
            while (index != -1) {
               text = text.replace(toReplace, Dictionary[x][y]);
               index = text.search(toReplace);
            }
        }

        text = text.replace(/\./g, function() {
            return Math.random() < 0.5 ? ". arrrrrrrrr" : "."
        });
        return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1);
    }

    var clear_click = function() {
    $("output1").value = "";
    $("output2").value = "";
}

window.onload = function() {
    $("clear").onclick = clear_click;
}



/*for (var x in Dictionary) {
    for (var y in Dictionary[x])
        console.log (y, Dictionary[x][y]);
}*/
```

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> Pirate Translator </title>
      <script src="js/test2.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Jacob's Pirate Translator</h1>
        <p>Simply click on the buttons to translate<br />
           words and/or phrases from English to pirate talk.
        <hr />
    <form name="TalkForm">

        <table>
        <tr><td align="center"><b>English</b>
            <td>
            <td align="center"><b>Pirate</b>
        <tr><td><textarea name="English" id="output1" rows=12 cols=35 wrap="virtual"></textarea> </td>
            <td align="center"> <br />
                <input type="button" value="Translate --->" 
                       onclick="document.TalkForm.Pirate.value =
                                  Translate(document.TalkForm.English.value);"> </td>
            <td><textarea name="Pirate" id="output2" rows=12 cols=35 wrap="virtual"></textarea> </td>
            <input type="button" id="clear" value="clear">
        </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't iterate over your data? What have you done to debug the problem? Do you get any errors in the console? The ` <input type="button" id="clear" value="clear">` is definitely invalid there.

Comment: Well it does iterate over my data, at the bottom of my js file you can see I have a for in loop that prints to the console and it prints out all of my objects, I just can't figure out where I went wrong trying to get the right output I am looking for in the text area.

Comment: What is the right output? What output are you currently getting?

Comment: Sorry, just a poorly worded question I guess?

Comment: so I am trying to make it so when someone types in an english phrase, like "hello", then clicks the translate button the other text area will will display the pirate translation like "ahoy"

Comment: right now when I type hello in the first box, it prints hello in the second

Comment: So the output is the same as the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT2: I've modified your Dictionary. If you follow the format of my Dictionary you can go as deep of arrays as you want. It should work. I've tested with your examples in all different kinds of orders and with text not found in the dictionary. Feel free to try it out.

And to add to the challenge, I made recursive functions. :D No for/while loops.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/f296h/8/)

```
var Dictionary = {
    hello: "ahoy",
    hi: "yohoho",
    pardon: [1, {
        me: "avast"
    }],
    excuse: [1, {
        me: "arrr"
    }],
    stranger: "scurvy",
    sir: "matey",
    madam: "proud beauty",
    miss: "comely wench",
    officer: "foul blaggart",
    enemy: "scallywag",
    where: [1, {
        is: "whar be"
    }],
    can: [4, {
        you_help_me_find: "know ye"
    }],
    is: [1, {
        that: "be that"
    }],
    how: [4, {
        far_is_it_to: "how many leagues to"
    }],
    the: "th",
    a: "a briny",
    any: "some godforsaken",
    nearby: "broadside",
    my: "me",
    your: "yer",
    old: "barnacle-covered",
    attractive: "comely",
    happy: "grog-filled",
    restroom: "head",
    restaurant: "galley",
    hotel: "fleabag inn",
    mall: "market",
    pub: "Skull & Scuppers",
    bank: "buried trasure",
    would: [1, {
        like: "be needin"
    }],
    I: [
        [1, {
            desire: "I have a fierce fire in me belly"
        }],
        [5, {
            wish_I_knew_how_to: "I be hankerin to"
        }]
    ],
    my: [
        [4, {
            mother_told_me_to: "me dear ol mum, bless her black soul, tol me to"
        }],
        [4, {
            companion_would_like_to: "me mate, ol Rumpot, wants to"
        }]
    ],
    find: "come across",
    take: [2, {
        a_nap: "have a bit of a lie down"
    }],
    make: [2, {
        a_withdrawal: "seize all yer doubloons"
    }],
    have: [2, {
        a_cocktail: "swill a pint or two of grog"
    }],
    kill: [1, {
        him: "blow the man down"
    }],
    frown: "hang the jib",
    take: [2, {
        a_hike: "walk the plank"
    }]

};

function translate(text) {
    var hop = 1;
    var textToReturn = "";
    //checking if the text is already split, if not we split
    if (typeof text === 'string') {
        text = text.split(' ');
    }
    if (text.length > 0) {
        if (typeof Dictionary[text[0]] == 'undefined' || typeof Dictionary[text[0]] === 'string') {
            textToReturn = (Dictionary[text[0]] || text[0]);
            text = text.slice(hop, text.length);
        } else {
           var info = recursiveCheck(text, Dictionary[text[0]]);
            textToReturn =  (info.hop == 1) ? text[0] : info.text;
            text = text.splice(info.hop, text.length);
        }
        if(text.length > 0)
        {
             textToReturn += ' ' + translate(text);  
        }

    }
    return textToReturn;
}
function recursiveCheck(text, arr)
{
    var found = {hop:1, text: ''};
    if(arr.length > 0)
    {
        if(typeof parseInt(arr[0]) === 'number' && text.length-1 >= arr[0])
        {
            var phrase = text.slice(1, arr[0]+1);
            if(arr[1][phrase.join('_')])
            {
                 found.hop = arr[0]+1;
                 found.text = arr[1][phrase.join('_')];
            }
        }
        else
        {
             found = recursiveCheck(text, arr[0] || []);  
             if(found.hop == 1 && arr.length > 1)
             {
                  found = recursiveCheck(text, arr.slice(1, arr.length));
             }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
var tra = document.getElementById('translate');
var pir = document.getElementById('pirate');
pir.disabled = true;
var eng = document.getElementById('english');

eng.onkeyup = function(){
     pir.value = "";   
}
tra.onclick = function () {
    pir.value = translate(eng.value);
};
```

HERE is an example of a deep array if you want to go further with the dictionary:

```
...
        I: [
            [1, {
                desire: [
                          [1,{ a: "I have a fierce fire in me belly"}],
                          [1,{ one: "I have one fierce fire in me belly"}]

            }],
            [5, {
                wish_I_knew_how_to: "I be hankerin to"
            }]
        ],
...
```

Of course I haven't tried it yet, but you can if you actually need it to work. Good luck.

EDIT: The point of this code is to show how to access your list. You don't seem to be using categories in your code, so why have them?

Your list looks a bit complex for a simple translation. Last I checked, dictionaries don't have categories.. Joke aside I've simplified your list.

```
var Dictionary = {
        hello:"ahoy",
        hi:"yohoho",
        pardon_me:"avast",
        excuse_me:"arrr",
        stranger:"scurvy",
        sir:"matey",
        madam:"proud beauty",
        miss:"comely wench",
        officer:"foul blaggart",
        enemy:"scallywag",
        where_is:"whar be",
        can_you_help_me_find:"know ye",
        is_that:"be that",
        how_far_is_it_to:"how many leagues to",
        the:"th",
        a:"a briny",
        any:"some godforsaken",
        nearby:"broadside",
        my:"me",
        your:"yer",
        old:"barnacle-covered",
        attractive:"comely",
        happy:"grog-filled",
        restroom:"head",
        restaurant:"galley",
        hotel:"fleabag inn",
        mall:"market",
        pub:"Skull & Scuppers",
        bank:"buried trasure",
        I_would_like_to:"I be needin to",
        I_desire:"I have a fierce fire in me belly",
        I_wish_I_knew_how_to:"I be hankerin to",
        my_mother_told_me_to:"me dear ol mum, bless her black soul, tol me to",
        my_companion_would_like_to:"me mate, ol Rumpot, wants to",
        find:"come across",
        take_a_nap:"have a bit of a lie down",
        make_a_withdrawal:"seize all yer doubloons",
        have_a_cocktail:"swill a pint or two of grog",
        kill_him:"blow the man down",
        frown:"hang the jib",
        take_a_hike:"walk the plank"

};

function translate(text)
{
    pir.value = Dictionary[text.split(' ').join('_')] || 'not found';

}

var tra = document.getElementById('translate');
var pir = document.getElementById('pirate');
pir.disabled = true;
var eng = document.getElementById('english');

tra.onclick = function(){ translate(eng.value) };
```

html:

```
<input id="english" type="text" placeholder="english"/>
<input id="pirate" placeholder="pirate"/>
<button id="translate">Translate</button>
```

I've simplified the code (by a lot) so I could get a simple working model.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/f296h/2/

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was trying to be a little too specific.  I appreciate the simplicity. lol I always seem to look way more into it than need be.  You helped a lot!

Comment: No prob, make sure to mark this as the right answer. Good luck. :D

Comment: so I am trying to make this work with the user being able to type more than one term in the box and have it output a string of pirate terms.  ie. if they type "hello stranger" I would like it to output "ahoy scurvy" right now if you type more than one term it outputs undefined.

Comment: Updated. I've changed quite a many things. Check my edit to see the modifications. Took me a couple hours. I like a challenge.